# How to parse a csv file delimited by '\x01' in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, delimiter

How to parse a csv file delimited by `\x01` in python and extract only a particular column.

Comment: Did you try this? Are you getting any issues?

Comment: yes i am gettign error message and i shared my details